# Safe option to handle NTFS on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, ntfs

What are the risks associated with the following methods and which one is the less likely to damage the OS or the drive?

- Tuxera/Paragon
- OSX "native" NTFS support (via terminal tweak)
- Windows Virtual Machine

http://www.remosoftware.com/info/how-to-mount-a-ntfs-drive-on-mac-os-x

> But sometimes working with third party applications will be rigorous because the third party applications will convert the files from NTFS to HFS+ or HFSX. In certain times, the conversion will be troublesome. Like trying to access a compressed files of size 9 GB, there appears the application crash and the drive will be unreadable further.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS

> Native NTFS write support has been discovered in Mac OS X 10.6 and later, but is not activated by default, although workarounds do exist to enable the functionality. However, user reports indicate the functionality is unstable and tends to cause kernel panics, probably the reason why write support has not been enabled or advertised.

Comment: I don't think that outer solutions could be safer as the Apple provided one. I think, Apple disabled the NTFS Write by default not because the unsafety, but because they couldn't assure, that the microsoft doesn't "invents" some "surprise" in the future. They won't accept the risk, that their OS will harm for example the partitions of the windows 10 sp 2 users in the future.